# How to cast List<Map<?, ?>> into List<Map<String, String>>?

Tags: java, casting

I am making bukkit plugin and one function returns `List<Map<?, ?>>`, if I to do that:

```
List<Map<String, String>> circle = FileManager.area.getMapList("circles");
```

I get error that it can't be converted. What do to?

The error:

```
List<Map<?, ?>> cannot be converted into List<Map<String, String>>
```

Comment: What's your exact error. Always post your exact error when asking a question. Errors are meaningful responses by any programming language. Not posting one is like saying "My car broke please help" and attaching a picture of the car.

Comment: exact error - List<Map<?, ?>> cannot be converted into List<Map<String, String>>

Comment: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bb/Barcroft_1100_Thomas_St_Car_Damaged_by_Tree_(7536694422).jpg -- please help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can cast away all the generics by casting to the raw type, `(List)`:

```
List<Map<String, String>> circle = (List) FileManager.area.getMapList("circles");
```

Note that as with most casts this is unsafe - it's better to find a way to pass the correct type information through, as other answers suggest.

Answer (score 1):

`getMapList` returns the type `List<Map<?, ?>> into List<Map<String, String>>`. Since generics are invariant you need to match the types

```
List<Map<?, ?>> circle = FileManager.area.getMapList("circles");
```

Comment: Can't use `List<Map<Object, Object>>` instead?

Comment: Sorry but thats method of bukkit's API, i can't change it

Comment: @MarounMaroun Not even that, compiler is very particular about types, only exact mapping allowed. Remember `?` is a source collection, PECS, etc

Comment: @XsergeiX this answer suggests to change your declaration not that of the API

Answer (score 1):

`Map<String, String>` is a subtype of `Map<?, ?>`, but since generics are not invariant this does not mean that `List<Map<String, String>>` is a subtype of `List<Map<?, ?>>`.

If you are certain that all the keys and values are `String` instances you can do this

```
List<Map<String, String>> circle = (List<Map<String, String>>) (Object) FileManager.area.getMapList("circles");
```

However I wouldn't recommend it because if any of the keys or values are not `String`s you may get a `ClassCastException` later on, so you are throwing away the guarantee that generics are supposed to provide.

An alternative would be to create a `new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>()` and iterate over the `List<Map<?, ?>>`, then use `instanceof` to check all the keys and values in each `Map<?, ?>` are `String`. Only if the `instanceof` checks succeed should you add the entry.

Answer (score 0):

is mostly used for assigning from some defined value like:
    Map m = new HashMap();

And using  is not good, because you need to explicitly cast it(which means that you know your runtime type beforehand).

Usually you explicitly specify the return values.So let's see by cases:

1) You want to write very generic function which gets string and returns List>, then you can write like this

```
<K, V> List<Map<K, V>> getMapList(String s) {
      ... 
}
```

Java will inference the type of K, V depending on what you're assigning to.

2) You want to return some specific type, then use that type:

```
<Integer, String> List<Map<Integer, String>> getMapList(String s) {
      ... 
}
```